# Doing both delete and insert records action in the same transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I found that in rails destroy method, an additional transaction would wrapped on the query. Therefore, when I trying to the following it does not work.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
 @model_a.destroy_all
 @new_model_list.each do |item|
  item.create!
  # Error occurs some point
  # No rollback for those deleted records
 end
end
```

Comment: The correct way to use ActiveRecord Transaction is to either use `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` or `SomeModel.transaction`. I'm not sure how your code runs the destroy_all line.

Comment: My fault. I missed ::Base part. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite this to:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do 
 @model_a.destroy_all
 @new_model_list.each do |item|
  item.create!
  # Error occurs some point
  # No rollback for those deleted records
 end
end
```